# Can a Javascript function level const variable take on a different value each time the function is called?

Tags: javascript, function, static, constants, local

I'm trying to find out if my use of 'const' is appropriate given the behavior I am seeing.

```
function showInstructions() {

    const againText = (clickCounter > 0) ? "again " : "";

    my2DContext.fillText("Click " + againText + "to try to do the thing", myCanvas.clientWidth / 2, myCanvas.clientHeight / 2);
}
```

The first time this function is called, clickCounter is 0, and it displays:

> "Click to try to do the thing"

called later, when clickCounter > 0, the function displays:

> "Click again to try to do the thing"

This works as intended.

Is this an appropriate use of 'const'?  Should this be the expected behavior?  Does it match other languages?

Comment: Hi, could you format your code properly?

Comment: Yes. Yes. And yes.

Comment: Certainly.  But it looks like someone beat me to it.  Sorry, n00b first SE post.  I didn't see a way to really preview my post when I wrote it.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Few languages have variables that when declared inside a function are shared between multiple calls to the function.

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with C/C++, and that's what I believe 'static' does...

Comment: Yes, but `const` is not `static`, and `static` variables inside of functions are the extraordinary case. Normal variables are scoped to the function call, in the huge majority of all languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can a Javascript function level const variable take on a different value each time the function is called?

Yes, as your example shows.

> Is this an appropriate use of 'const'?

Yes. However it would be more appropriate if `clickCounter` was declared as a parameter of the function.

> Should this be the expected behavior?

Yes, it's the same as `var`, `let` or `function`: a declaration inside a function is creating a new **local variable** in the scope of that function on every call.

> Does it match other languages?

Yes. Few languages have variables that when declared inside a function are shared between multiple calls to the function.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a Javascript function level const variable take on a different value each time the function is called?

**Short answer:** Yes

---

**Long answer**

I tried to recreate a quick runnable code base on your example.

- Every time the click event has triggered the expression in `againText` variable will be evaluated (ternary operator) and a new value is assigned to the `againText` variable.

This is normal behaviour, this happens only once the function is called, an error will only occur when you try to reassign a value to the `againText` within the function.

```js
function showInstructions() {
  let clickCounter = document.getElementById("click").value;
  const againText = Number(clickCounter) > 0 ? "again " : "";
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML =
    "Click " + againText + "to try to do the thing";
}

document
  .getElementById("btn")
  .addEventListener("click", showInstructions);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="click" />
<button id="btn">click</button>
<p id="text"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

In javascript 'const' can not be reassigned but it is mutable, so yeah i think this an appropriate use of 'const'
You can read more about const on MDN docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: "*can not be reassigned but it is mutable*" doesn't make sense.

Comment: The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable—just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned.Hope it make sense now

Comment: @kuuhak-u Whether the value it holds is mutable (an object) or not (a primitive) depends on the value, not on the variable being `const`.